# How many of the sequential primeconcatenations are prime?

Tags: number-theory, statistics, soft-question, prime-numbers

- 2 is a prime. 3 is the next prime. 23 is also a prime.
- 31 is a prime. 37 is the next prime. 3137 is also a prime.

Can we estimate or prove how many $XY$ are prime if $X$ and $Y$ are primes nr $n$ and $n+1$?

I know this is dependent on basis. I will for this question assume basis 10.

(Optional question) Can we prove whether lower or higher basis will increase or decrease occurrance?

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A030461](https://oeis.org/A030461).  I would conjecture that $XY$'s probability of being prime is of the same order of magnitude as the probability for any number of the same size, thus $\sim constant/n$ as $n \to \infty$.  But I doubt that much can be proven in the current state of the art.

Comment: @RobertIsrael wow that database sure has some unexpected things!

Comment: The word is base not basis.

Comment: Ah so it's another of those perception tricks. Didn't work to discourage me from  learning Russian either, did it?

Comment: @mathreadler Do you mean "how many in some range" ? Because we can expect (although a proof is probably infeasible) that infinite many primes of this type exist.

Comment: @Peter Hmm I suppose it would be quite fast to calculate for all XY up to.. 32 bits with some sieve. For bigger than that, I don't know. I also expect it could be infinite and difficult to disprove.

Comment: @mathreadler There are programs that can handle much larger numbers, like pari, pfgw , Python, etc. Are you interested in the count for some limits for the first prime ?

Comment: Yes there are such programs, but computational speed slows down when there is need for arbitrary big precision. I suppose some kind of histogram could be interesting, to get some feeling for their distribution.

Comment: 4110 below 1 million,  33819 below 10 million. for primes that create them.

Comment: Note that a some primes can be decomposed into more than one pairs e.g. $(19,97)$ and $(199,7)$ both yield the prime $1997$ so we need to be careful if we want to include or not include multiple pairs for the same prime

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha interesting observation, but it does not apply to this question as I specifically ask for neighbouring primes.